# extending the django view

Tags: django, django-admin

Hello I need to extend the admin view for a model so I can retrieve the items I want and use them at the extended admin templete for that model.
I couldn't find enough docs about this.
d
Thanks

Comment: You might want to say what you've tried so far, what exactly it is you're trying to do. I can point you at some relevant documentation, but I've no idea if it's what you've already ready. You need to give more details!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls), it's new in 1.1:

Copying the relevant code from the link with some slight modifications, it's supposed to go into your app's `admin.py`:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('app.your_admin_views',
            (r'^my_view/$', self.my_view)
        )
        return my_urls + urls
```

You could place the new admin views in a file called `your_admin_views.py` under your app directory or whichever way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [that part of documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods) to override admin views, views for adding, changing, list page of the selected model, deleteing and displaying history respectively...

Here is the [documentation for overriding templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options)...